# How to make "ng-" to work with any attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Like `ng-enabled`, `ng-src`, `ng-class`
There is something generic that make it work for any attribte (`ng-x`)?

For example, this is my code:

```
<div ng-attrbuite1="a" ng-otherattribute="b"></div>
```

I want it to set:

```
<div attribute1="a_value" attribute2="b_value_in_scope">
```

In runtime I don't know yet, the names of the attribute that will be exists in the HTML.

Comment: I suggest you read about DIRECTIVES, this is a good article about the subject: http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: I recommend that you don't name your directives ng-*. See the 2nd best practice block https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives

Comment: no...there is nothing implicit in `ng-` unless the core directive actually exists

Comment: I know what is directives.  Searching for a smart shortcut if it exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are meaning you want to have a catch-all where all the attributes prefixed with say `my` (as you should use your own prefix) get evaluated and then set to their respective non-prefixed attribute you will need to:

1. Make your own custom directive
2. Find all attributes on the element (provided by $attrs)
3. Get the evaluated value
4. Set the actual attribute on the element

I won't cover making the actual directive you can find out that [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

In the `link` function of your directive one of the arguments will be [$attrs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes). `$attrs`contains the normalized(camel cased) and non-normalized attribute names, their respective evaluated values(if using expressions), and some helper methods.

So you can simply loop over the $attrs (or $attrs.$attr) keys, filtering out ones you shouldn't be using like ng-model, ng-selected, etc, get the evaluated value and then set the respective non-prefixed counterpart.

```
Object.keys($attrs).filter(function(key){
    //filter out keys like ngModel,ngSelect,$set etc
    return /^my/.test(key);
}).forEach(function(key){
    //$attrs.$attr contains the non-normalized 
    //versions of the attributes
    //this example assumes you will prefix with `my`
    //so remove `my-` to get the attribute name to set
    var attrName = $attrs.$attr[key].replace("my-","");

    //Use $parse() if you just want to use some scope's property name
    //for example my-attribute="somePropertyName"
     $attrs.$set(attrName,$parse($attrs[key])($scope));

    //Use just $attrs[key] if you are using some expression
    //for example my-attribute="{{somePropertyName}}"
     $attrs.$set(attrName,$attrs[key]);
});
```

```js
angular.module("test",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 
  $scope.someprop = "Some Value";
 
})
.directive("caAttr",function($parse){
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link : function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      console.log($attrs);
      Object.keys($attrs).filter(function(key){
        return /^my/.test(key);
      }).forEach(function(key){
        var attrName = $attrs.$attr[key].replace("my-","");
        $attrs.$set(attrName,$parse($attrs[key])($scope));
      });
      angular.element("#log").text( angular.element("#container").html() );
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div id="container">
    <div ng-model="mymodel" ng-selected="{{nothing}}" my-stack="someprop" ca-attr></div>
  </div>
  <div id="log"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use directives. Here is a simple example:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ui-foo="foo">foo scope variable: {{foo}}</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('uiFoo',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EAC',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        $scope.foo = attrs.uiFoo;
      }
    };
  }
);
```